# How can I trick SBS 2011 into allowing me to assign a UPN alias so users can logon as user@domain.com

Tags: hacking, windows-sbs, windows-sbs-2011, active-directory

How can I trick SBS 2011 into allowing me to assign a UPN alias so users can logon as user@domain.com

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243629/en-us

But on SBS I only have a 'General', 'Trusts', and 'Managed by' tab.. this is SBS 2011.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong set of properties. In ADD&T right click the "root" object, not the "domain" object, select properties, and add the UPN suffix.

Comment: Thanks! You fixed a lot of things in 1 go with your help there, specifically http://serverfault.com/questions/359153/outlook-autodiscover-authentication-to-iis-fails-as-domain-is-mail-contoso-com

Comment: Glad to help...